# What is the definition of "legacy code"?

Tags: definition, legacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes code legacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479596/what-makes-code-legacy)

What is the definition of "legacy code"?

Comment: The code no-one wants to deal with anymore?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I can't remember where I saw the expression (Pragmatic Programmer?) but one way to think about it is *code is legacy code as soon as it's written*.

Generally it's referred to code that gets inherited by a team or a programmer from somewhere else (external or internal).

I prefer the former definition, though. :)

Comment: This indeed is a great definition (and also in line with my definition, since I refuse to discuss my code with myself) :D

Comment: I read somewhere, how do you think of this: legacy code is code which you can't rely on, the code we wrote 5 minutes ago and doesn't have tests? legacy code.

Answer (score 58):

Channeling Michael Feathers: Code without tests.

Comment: Your response is the last one and I was looking for this definition because I'm reading the M.F book ) !

Comment: If someone dropped a folder of undocumented 1989 COBOL on you which ran on Unix but had 93% code coverage, would you not call it legacy?

Comment: @LukePuplett I believe a stream of thought exists in which "good" tests serve as (among other things) documentation of _actual_ behavior, which is often desired over other forms of documentation describing _desired_ behavior. Perhaps this stream of thought is what Jörg and Michael Feathers has in mind?

Answer (score 25):

Code someone else written (usually someone no longer available for any contact), but you must deal with it now.

Answer (score 23):

Code written by others or under a previous language, architecture, methodology, or framework that pertains to the current project.

Comment: Note: "the current project" is included because the term "legacy" implies ancestry.

Answer (score 16):

I would say that *legacy code* is (usually old) code that *can be rewritten using better programming techniques or languages*. Legacy code usually is not easily rewritten because of dependencies on that code.

Comment: Most code as created meets your definition of legacy code.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Seems to match the definition: `Code is legacy code as soon as it's written.`