# How to access private data members outside the class without making "friend"s?

Tags: c++, class, private, encapsulation, data-members

I have a `class A` as mentioned below:-

```
class A{
     int iData;
};
```

I neither want to create member function nor inherit the above `class A` nor change the specifier of `iData`.

My doubts:-

- How to access `iData` of an object say `obj1` which is an instance of `class A`?
- How to change or manipulate the `iData` of an object `obj1`?

**Note**: Don't use `friend`.

Comment: Can you change the declaration of that class at all?

Comment: No i dont want to change the declaration of that class.

Comment: It seems that in SO, you are verifying whether `private` access specifier works fine or not.

Comment: @greengit: The question was for my awareness that whether we can do by some or other way or not.

Comment: Sounds like 'How do I make it work if I don't want to change anything?'. Is it a legacy or third-party code which you can't change but you need to access that member?

Comment: @RocketR: Anyone has answer for `RocketR` question? :)

Comment: @Abhineet: Next time you post a Q, you post all your requirements/expectations at the time of asking and not change them once people start answering & down voting them for not noticing your edits. It is your responsibility as a Q poster to post a clear, concise Q.

Comment: @Als: Yes friend i am sorry for that. And thanks for your support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. That member is private, it's not visible outside the class. That's the whole point of the public/protected/private modifiers.

(You could probably use dirty pointer tricks though, but my guess is that you'd enter undefined behavior territory pretty fast.)

Comment: [friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function) [friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class) ... my friend :)

Comment: The question reads: `Please note: I dont want to use friend`.

Comment: @greengit: there is a worth in it, i have clarified my doubt. Atleasst for me it means a lot my friend. :)

Comment: "You can't" - so you're saying this is incorrect and/or UB?  http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html

Comment: @xaxxon: that code uses a `friend`-based trick.

Comment: @Mat if it's not UB, then perhaps you would consider changing your answer - especially because it's the accepted answer and people may take it to be accurate without reading all the comments.

Comment: @xaxxon: This question is about private access **without** using `friend`. Your article uses `friend`.

Comment: @Mat I guess you're technically right, but I would assume they meant not adding `friend` to the class where you want to get access.   There's no reason to artificially limit what can be done outside the class.

Answer (score 40):

Here's a way, not recommended though

```
class Weak {
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(const string& name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    string getName()const {
        return this->name;
    }

};

struct Hacker {
    string name;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Weak w;
    w.setName("Jon");
    cout << w.getName() << endl;
    Hacker *hackit = reinterpret_cast<Hacker *>(&w);
    hackit->name = "Jack";
    cout << w.getName() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Note -- If the class has a vtable (`std::is_polymorphic<T>()`) you need to declare an additional `void *` as the first member. Needless to say this is a dirty hack on top of another dirty hack - avoid doing it.

Comment: @dialer Can you expand on this? Maybe edit the answer or make a new followup answer?

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 14):

Bad idea, don't do it ever - but here it is how it can be done:

```
int main()
{
   A aObj;
   int* ptr;

   ptr = (int*)&aObj;

   // MODIFY!
   *ptr = 100;
}
```

Comment: This can result in undefined behavior. Not portable.

Comment: Absolutely! Inherit from other class, change pragma, add virtual functions, make it a union - I didn't say it was correct!

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer. It was a string of downvotes to may answers.

Comment: Never-mind. I was sure I would get a down-vote! :)

Answer (score 10):

---

> **EDIT:**
>   Just saw you edited the question to say that you don't want to use friend.
>   Then the answer is:

***NO you can't, atleast not in a portable way approved by the C++ standard.***

---

> *The later part of the Answer, was previous to the Q edit & I leave it here for benefit of >those who would want to understand a few concepts & not just looking an Answer to the >Question.*

---

If you have members under a Private access specifier then those members are only accessible from within the class. No outside Access is allowed.

***An Source Code Example:***

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int c;
    public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        c = 10;    //Allowed 
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.c = 30;     //Not Allowed, gives compiler error
    obj.doSomething();  //Allowed
}
```

***A Workaround: `friend` to rescue***
To access the private member, you can declare a function/class as friend of that particular class, and then the member will be accessible inside that function or class object without access specifier check.

***Modified Code Sample:***

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int c;

    public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        c = 10;    //Allowed 
    }

    friend void MytrustedFriend();    
};

void MytrustedFriend()
{
        MyClass obj;
        obj.c = 10; //Allowed
}

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.c = 30;     //Not Allowed, gives compiler error
    obj.doSomething();  //Allowed
    //Call the friend function
    MytrustedFriend();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But we can use making friend of class A.

Comment: `I dont want to create member function for above class A`. Also your `A::doSomething()` is private. This code results in compile error.

Comment: @iammilind: Can you not see `public` not being there a typo & well the answer in all completeness answers what options C++ provides. It also includes what fits his/her specification. I suggest you try having a broader view of things.

Comment: @Downvoters: Any explanations for your downvotes?

Comment: Would the second code example work if inside the friend function, you dereferenced the class to access the private member using the `->` operator? e.g. `MyClass* obj = /* ... */; obj->private_member = /* ... */;`

Answer (score 9):

http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

this guy's blog shows you how to do it using templates. With some modifications, you can adapt this method to access a private data member, although I found it tricky despite having 10+ years experience.

I wanted to point out like everyone else, that there is an extremely few number of cases where doing this is legitimate. However, I want to point out one: I was writing unit tests for a software suite. A federal regulatory agency requires *every single line of code* to be exercised and tested, *without* modifying the original code. Due to (IMHO) poor design, a static constant was in the 'private' section, but  I needed to use it in the unit test. So the method seemed to me like the best way to do it.

I'm sure the way could be simplified, and I'm sure there are other ways. I'm not posting this for the OP, since it's been 5 months, but hopefully this will be useful to some future googler.

Comment: `every single line of code to be exercised and tested` oh my. that's bitterly stupid. http://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf

Comment: @v.oddou Interesting article, but that's just an opinion. There are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/479622/). And of course these opinions are heavily disputed. We don't need to repeat that here. Just a question: when you refactor, how do you know you don't break things? I agree with Jim Coplien that "unit test" is not the answer to everything. But "not testing" is not a solution either.

Comment: Of course I don't agree with everything in this article. eg the "1 trillionth" coverage, is rhetoric crap (because of recurrence relation that he conveniently swept under the carpet). What you say is also valid. Also he is stupidely idealistic: `Tests should be designed with great care. Business people, rather than programmers` LLOL

Answer (score 5):

In C++, almost everything is possible! If you have no way to get private data, then you have to hack. Do it only for testing!

```
class A {
     int iData;
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    struct ATwin { int pubData; }; // define a twin class with public members
    reinterpret_cast<ATwin*>( &a )->pubData = 42; // set or get value

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alexander your code is not working.

Comment: I fixed the compilation issue with the example

Answer (score 3):

There's no legitimate way you can do it.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned above that i dont want to change the behaviour.

Comment: @RocketR: +1, to compensate downvotes for a Q that was edited and modified later on.

Comment: @Als: Earlier he has mentioned to do the following 
   struct A{
     int iData
   };
I have never told that i want to replace the keyword `class` with `struct`. And edition was to not to use friend not the other things...

Comment: @Abhineet: Given the wide context of the Q that was put forward when it was posted, I would not discount that as an outright wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start making `friend`s of `class A`. e.g.

```
void foo ();

class A{
  int iData;
  friend void foo ();
};
```

**Edit**:

If you can't change `class A` body then `A::iData` is not accessible with the given conditions in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`iData` is a `private` member of the class. Now, the word `private` have a very definite meaning, in C++ as well as in real life. It means **you can't touch it**. It's not a recommendation, it's the law. If you don't change the class declaration, you are not allowed to manipulate that member in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to access the private data of class directly in main and other's function...

here is a small code...

```
class GIFT
{
    int i,j,k;

public:
    void Fun() 
    {
        cout<< i<<" "<< j<<" "<< k;
    }

};

int main()
{
     GIFT *obj=new GIFT(); // the value of i,j,k is 0
     int *ptr=(int *)obj;
     *ptr=10;
     cout<<*ptr;      // you also print value of I
     ptr++;
     *ptr=15;
     cout<<*ptr;      // you also print value of J
     ptr++;
     *ptr=20; 
     cout<<*ptr;      // you also print value of K
     obj->Fun();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[friend](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) is your friend.

```
class A{
    friend void foo(A arg);
    int iData;
};

void foo(A arg){
     // can access a.iData here
}
```

If you're doing this regularly you should probably reconsider your design though.

Answer (score -1):

access private members outside  class ....only for study purpose ....
This program accepts all the below conditions
"I dont want to create member function for above class A. And also i dont want to inherit the above class A. I dont want to change the specifier of iData."

//here member function is used only to input and output the private values ...
//**void hack()** is defined outside the class...

```
//GEEK MODE....;)
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

    class A
    {
    private :int iData,x;
    public: void get()             //enter the values
        {cout<<"Enter iData : ";
            cin>>iData;cout<<"Enter x : ";cin>>x;}

        void put()                               //displaying values
    {cout<<endl<<"sum = "<<iData+x;}
};

void hack();        //hacking function

void main()
{A obj;clrscr();
obj.get();obj.put();hack();obj.put();getch();
}

void hack()         //hack begins
{int hck,*ptr=&hck;
cout<<endl<<"Enter value of private data (iData or x) : ";
cin>>hck;     //enter the value assigned for iData or x
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{ptr++;
if(*ptr==hck)
{cout<<"Private data hacked...!!!\nChange the value : ";
cin>>*ptr;cout<<hck<<" Is chaged to : "<<*ptr;
return;}
}cout<<"Sorry value not found.....";
}
```