# Can Private data members accessed using Public Pointer to it in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, private, member, public

How to access id using `ptr`?

```
class A
{
    int id;
public:
    int *ptr;
};


void main()
{
    int A::* ptr = &A :: id;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access private data members outside the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717163/how-to-access-private-data-members-outside-the-class)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class A { 
    int id;
public:
    int *ptr= &id;
};
```

You can use the variable pointer to access id.