# Access a private static member outside the class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, private-members

Non-static private members can be hacked into [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282638/1715765), but what about static members?

```
class Foo {
private:
    static std::vector<int> secrets;
}
```

Suppose I want to test `Foo` and I need to get at or change the private static stuff. If it's supposed to stick around as a permanent unit test, it would make sense to just declare `friend class FooTest;`, but maybe it's not so permanent and I prefer to keep things clean. Or maybe I just can't edit `Foo` for whatever reason. Can I hack it?

Comment: afaik the answer you link is UB, but there are legal ways to access a private member too.

Comment: Usually when developers mark things `private` inside the class, it means they are not part of observable behaviour, they are implementation details, and they can change without breaking the user interfaces. So, there should be the way to test your system without hacking around and modifying private parts. On the other hand, the library design might be simply bad.

Comment: you should write code in a way that it can be tested without hacks. What is `Foo`? What is `secrets`? Typically you test public methods that use the private parts. I mean, if nobody can call `secrets`, why bother to test it?

Comment: writing tests is to make refactoring simpler (among other things). Testing private members rather achieves the opposite. Tests will have to be modified even though the api of a class does not change.

Comment: Unit testing should test the behavior and public interface of classes. You create an object in a certain way, call a function, and expect some specific result. How the function is implemented, and what private data is in the class, doesn't really matter and is irrelevant to the test.

Comment: In my case, the situation is that I want all (normal) access of `FooProxy` to go through `FooController` methods (and `fooProxy` needs to be a static member for specific and annoying reasons), and there are some things I want to test during development without adding them to the API. It would be a convenience to not have to touch anything outside the `FooTest` class.

Comment: For that I would create two sets of tests: One for `FooController` and one for `FooProxy`. You could use *mocking* for the internal/wrapped/proxied class to return well-known responses for its public interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I hack it?

Yes, even though it is trivial to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173080/12002570) for `static` member instead of a non-static member, here is the working modified example. The only thing that is different here from the original answer is the syntax used for a `static` field. *Everything else is the same* as the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173080/12002570).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
class Foo {
private:
    static std::vector<int> secrets;
};
std::vector<int> Foo::secrets = {1,1,1};

// tag used to access Foo::member
struct Foo_member { 
  
  using type = std::vector<int>*;
  friend type get(Foo_member);
};
template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};
//explicit instantiation
template struct Rob<Foo_member, &Foo::secrets>;

int main() {
  std::cout << "Before: ";
  for(const auto &elem: *get(Foo_member()))  
  { 
     std::cout << elem << " ";
  } 
  *get(Foo_member()) = {4,2,6}; //overwrite the private field's value!!
  std::cout << "\nAfter: " ;
  for(const auto &elem: *get(Foo_member()))  
  { 
     std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nWa1ec4od)

---

You can also use lvalue reference instead of pointers in the above example so that you don't have to dereference the result of `get` again and again. [Demo with lvalue reference instead of pointer](https://godbolt.org/z/91PMPf4Wo)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used move semantics before but I figured out that if `Foo::secrets` happens to be a `unique_ptr`, I can move it with `auto&& m = get(Foo_member())` (in the lvalue example). I don't suppose I need to move it back afterwards, but out of curiosity, could this be done?

Comment: Nevermind, `auto&` works fine...